Gedit Bracket match is out of range
Gedit matches brackets like { with } and tells us where the matching opening/closing bracket is. If it is more than 10000 characters, it says "Bracket match is out of range" instead. How would one go about extending that range?
I've got the newest version of Ubuntu and Gedit came with it.
Here https://github.com/jaseemabid/gedit I found gedit-master/gedit/gedit-window.c which says in ln.2236-2270
static void
bracket_matched_cb (GtkSourceBuffer           *buffer,
            GtkTextIter               *iter,
            GtkSourceBracketMatchType  result,
            GeditWindow               *window)
{
    if (buffer != GTK_SOURCE_BUFFER (gedit_window_get_active_document (window)))
        return;

    switch (result)
    {
        case GTK_SOURCE_BRACKET_MATCH_NONE:
            gtk_statusbar_pop (GTK_STATUSBAR (window->priv->statusbar),
                       window->priv->bracket_match_message_cid);
            break;
        case GTK_SOURCE_BRACKET_MATCH_OUT_OF_RANGE:
            gedit_statusbar_flash_message (GEDIT_STATUSBAR (window->priv->statusbar),
                               window->priv->bracket_match_message_cid,
                               _("Bracket match is out of range"));
            break;
        case GTK_SOURCE_BRACKET_MATCH_NOT_FOUND:
            gedit_statusbar_flash_message (GEDIT_STATUSBAR (window->priv->statusbar),
                               window->priv->bracket_match_message_cid,
                               _("Bracket match not found"));
            break;
        case GTK_SOURCE_BRACKET_MATCH_FOUND:
            gedit_statusbar_flash_message (GEDIT_STATUSBAR (window->priv->statusbar),
                               window->priv->bracket_match_message_cid,
                               _("Bracket match found on line: %d"),
                               gtk_text_iter_get_line (iter) + 1);
            break;
        default:
            g_assert_not_reached ();
    }
}

So in case the result is GTK_SOURCE_BRACKET_MATCH_OUT_OF_RANGE we get this message. I couldn't figure out where the bracket_matched_cb method is called, this is as far as I got.

This might be more suited to stackoverflow, but since I took a quick look...,
The place you point out is the only place where GTK_SOURCE_BRACKET_MATCH_OUT_OF_RANGE appears in that source code tree, and bracket_matched_cb() is set as a callback elsewhere in gedit-window.c with g_signal_connect (doc, "bracket-matched", G_CALLBACK (bracket_matched_cb), window);. That hints at bracket matching being a feature of the UI element, so somewhere in a library outside gedit itself.
Now, it's not in the GTK source as far as I can tell, but the gtksourceview library  looks to have it.
And, in gtksourceview/gtksourcebuffer.c we seem to have a hard-coded limit:
#define BRACKET_MATCHING_CHARS_LIMIT  10000

and
/* Note that we only look BRACKET_MATCHING_CHARS_LIMIT at most.
 * @pos is moved to the bracket match, if found.
 */
static GtkSourceBracketMatchType
find_bracket_match_real (GtkSourceBuffer *buffer,
             GtkTextIter     *pos)
...
    if (char_count >= BRACKET_MATCHING_CHARS_LIMIT)
    {
        return GTK_SOURCE_BRACKET_MATCH_OUT_OF_RANGE;
    }
...

I didn't check the exact code or library version Ubuntu has... it's probably in one of the lib*gtksourceview* packages, or whatever the source package is.
